# Using sscanf for reading data separated by |

Tags: c, file, scanf

I have to read data from a .txt file, this is a sample of the data:

```
1 |    SMAX 0.3848 | 0.234 | 0.15
```

I am only interested on reading the first, third and fourth column (so I want to discard that weird SMAX 0.3848). So far I have this:

```
while(fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fp) != NULL)
{
    sscanf(buffer, "%d | %*s | %lf | %lf", &id, &ra, &dec);
}
```

However it does not work, I think it is because of the "SMAX 0.3848", and I am incorrectly discarding it. My question is, how could I read this data?

Note: There are many columns in my dataset, and there are other "weird data" that I will need to discard.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `"%*s"` it stops scanning when it finds a white space, try this<sup>1</sup>

```
if (sscanf(buffer, "%d |%*[^|]|%lf |%lf", &id, &ra, &dec) == 3)
    /* proceed to use `id', `ra', `dec' */
else
    /* invalid line of input */
```

To understand what the `"%*[^|]"` means/does read the manual page for [`scanf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Use meaningful variable names, with todays text editors it's no extra work as the autocomplete feature will help you a lot, meaningful variable names will make the program easy to understand a few months/weeks later when you get back to it for some reason (maintenance, reuse).</sub>

Comment: I can't argue with you @chux you are an expert in `scanf()`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead write like this -

```
  if(sscanf(buffer, "%d | %*[^%|] | %lf | %lf", &id, &ra, &dec)==3){
  /*                      ^ this will read until | is not encountered and then discard it*/
  // do something
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading for `"%s"` (or any variant thereof) will stop reading at a space.